# Detect extreme (most distant) points in numpy-3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have a large numpy 3D array (45900, 3, 3). In each 3x3 subset of this array I have one cluster with a unique ID (clusters have a value higher than 0). My challenge is to find the 'extreme points' of each cluster in each subset. With 'extreme points' I mean the two points that are furthest away in the cluster. **Thus, it has nothing to do with the values of these points, only with the location.**

An example subset is:

```
numpy3D= array([[[1, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0]],

[[0, 0, 2],
[0, 0, 2],
[0, 0, 2]],

[[3, 3, 3],
[3, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0]],

[[4, 0, 0],
[0, 4, 0],
[0, 0, 4]]])
```

As output I would like an array representing the x, y and z coordinates of the 'extreme points'.

For example:

```
#output
array([[ 0., 0., 0.],
[ 0., 0., 2.],
[ 1., 0., 2.],
[ 1., 2., 2.],
[ 2., 1., 0.],
[ 2., 0., 2.],
[ 3., 0., 0.],
[ 3., 0., 2.],
[ 4., 0., 0.],
[ 4., 2., 2.]])
```

Where the first column represents the subset location and the second and third the x an y coordinates of each extreme point. So in this case numpy3D[0,0,0] is the coordinate of the first extreme point in the first 3x3 subset and numpy3D[0,0,2] the coordinate of the second extreme point in this subset.

Any ideas on this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "each 2d subset of this array"?

Comment: For example the 3 by 3 2d array that you will get with: numpy3D[0]

Comment: But a 3 by 3 would be x,y,z coordinate, not x,y.

Comment: you're right! So what I need is the x-coordinate of the subset location and the y,z coordinates of the extreme points. I will edit my question.

Comment: And what do these 3x3 2D matrices represent?

Comment: I've proposed a solution that, hopefully, is adaptable to your problem. The thing is from your explanation there seems to be no unique x, for y,z pairs as you say. `numpy3D[0][0]` will return a triplet, not a duple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) can be used to solve this problem in an elegant and vectorized manner:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
idx = np.indices(numpy3D.shape).reshape(numpy3D.ndim, numpy3D.size)
groups = npi.group_by(numpy3D, axis=None)
label, min = groups.min(idx, axis=1)
label, max = groups.max(idx, axis=1)
```

Note that creating the group-by object is the most expensive part of this calculation; performing various different reductions over those groups afterwards is a trivial operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, This is exactly what I need